# Search algorithm to find symbols with and without "-" sign

Tags: php, search, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

On my `prestashop` 1.6 store I've got problem with search algorithm. Every product has got compatibility in description, and it looks like: "DCP-9015". I want search algorithm to find it when user is looking by word: "DCP9015". 
I don't have any idea how to make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Search Alias tool. In your Backoffice go to `Preferences` > `Search` and at the top click on `Add new Alias`.

Here you can provide an Alias for `DCP-9015`. In the `Alias` field type "DCP9015" and in the `Result` field type "DCP-9015".

Save and repeat this operation for every alias you need to create.

If you got a lot of aliases you can do it programmatically. If you really want you can also override `indexation()` method in `/classes/Search.php`, but that will needs more work.

Comment: Thanks. There is a lot of aliases (10000+) so I'll try to change it programmatically. :)

Answer (score -1):

You should try `Replace` function of the mysql as below way :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_XY
WHERE REPLACE(field2,'-','') LIKE '%' + field1 + '%'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Prestashop Search Engine.